# Что если во время отладки выскакивает окно с #######.cs файл не найден

Tags: c#, visual-studio, htmlagilitypack

Смотрите, во время отладки выскакивает вот такое окно: [image]
я как понимаю, это (наверное) должно решаться в настройках Visual Studio но как это вопрос.

Comment: скорее всего была попытка зайти в библиотечную функцию. при этом исходники этой библиотеки отсутствуют

Comment: Grundy. Здравствуйте! Спасибо за комментарий. А обязательно иметь исходники используемой библиотеке для отладки приложения?

Comment: Если не пытаться забраться внутрь библиотеки - то не обязательно.

Comment: Для отладки своего приложения - конечно не обязательно. Здесь ошибка в том, что идет попытка войти внутри _библиотечной функции_. Если не заходить внутрь - то и ошибки не будет. Так же стоит проверить настройку `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debugger` галочку `"Enable Just my Code"` если она снята, стоит ее поставить

Comment: Извините, но вы случайно не знаете как это же выглядеть но с русским интерфейсом? =)

Comment: И как не заходить во внутрь библиотечной функции?

Comment: Спасибо всё сделал! Благодаря вас. =)

Comment: @MacAntony, добавь тогда ответ как делал :-)